# Swagger showing incorrect query param

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

I have this controller and action method:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AppointmentController : ControllerBase
{        
    [Route("{provider}/AvailableSlots")]
    [HttpGet]        
    public Task<AvailableSlotsResponse> GetAvailableSlots(Request<AvailableSlotsRequest> request)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here's the model:

```
    public class Request<T> where T : class
    {
        [FromRoute]
        public string Provider { get; set; }
        [FromQuery(Name = "")]
        public T Model { get; set; }
    }

    public class AvailableSlotsRequest
    {
        //[FromQuery(Name = "Location")] //Would prefer not to have to use this
        public string Location { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to use `Location` as the query param name in the URL in order to hit the endpoint, as expected.

eg. `http://localhost/api/Appointment/Company/AvailableSlots?Location=SYD`

However, when I view the Swagger page, the parameter is called `Model.Location` which is confusing for consumers of my API:

[image: swagger]

I can use `[FromQuery(Name = "Location")]` to force Swagger to display `Location`, however this feels very redundant and duplicates the property name.

Here is my Swagger set up in `ConfigureServices()`:

```
services.AddSwaggerDocument(document =>
            {
                document.PostProcess = d =>
                {
                    d.Info.Version = Configuration["APIVersion"];
                    d.Info.Title = $"{Configuration["ApplicationName"]} {Configuration["DomainName"]} API";
                };
            });
```

How can I make Swagger display `Location` instead of `Model.Location`, without having to duplicate the word "Location" in the `[FromQuery]` attribute?

Comment: Not that focused on answering the question but I can't avoid asking: Do you really need to wrap two strings params into a generic class? That seems to just add noise and complexity. Unless, of course, you have a good reason for it.

Comment: @jpgrassi It's actually a more complicated model but to keep the question simple I just left the Location string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I had to use `[FromQuery(Name = "<PropertyName>")]`.

However I found a better way:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AppointmentController : ControllerBase
{        
    [Route("{provider}/AvailableSlots")]
    [HttpGet]        
    public Task<AvailableSlotsResponse> GetAvailableSlots(AvailableSlotsRequest request)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public class Request
{
    [FromRoute]
    public string ProviderName { get; set; }
}

public class AvailableSlotsRequest : Request
{
    [FromQuery]
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

This also means the model can use any attribute, compared to my first attempt where the `T Model` was decorated with `[FromQuery]`

Answer (score 2):

Add to the controller parameter the attribute `[FromRoute]`:

```
    public Task<AvailableSlotsResponse> GetAvailableSlots([FromRoute]Request<AvailableSlotsRequest> request)
```

Remove the attribute `FromQuery` in the Model property and uncomment the attribute `FromQuery` from de Location Property.

[image]

Comment: I might not have made the question clear enough (I just updated it now). I'd prefer to not have to use [FromQuery(Name = "Location")] since that's exactly what the property is called.